# Could an implicit compiler created default constructor have more than a null body?

Tags: c++, winapi, constructor, x86, default-constructor

Could an implicit compiler created default constructor have more than a null body?
According to [IBM's website](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.2.0?topic=only-default-constructors-c), the answer is: no.

I have this project that's kind of stumping me though:

This is where an instance of a class called StackWalkerToConsole with no defined default constructor gets declared:

```cpp
void func5()
{
  StackWalkerToConsole sw;
  ...
}
```

This somehow causes one of the user-defined constructors of its **parent class** to get called:

```cpp
StackWalker::StackWalker(int options, LPCSTR szSymPath, DWORD dwProcessId, HANDLE hProcess)
{
  // The function has a body, I just removed it for clarity's sake.
  ...
}
```

So I put a breakpoint on this constructor, and using the callstack I looked at the default constructor for StackWalkerToConsole. Since it's not defined in the source code, I could only look at its dissassembly:

```
StackWalker_VC2017.exe!StackWalkerToConsole::StackWalkerToConsole(void):
0000000140008210  mov         qword ptr [rsp+8],rcx  
0000000140008215  push        rdi  
0000000140008216  sub         rsp,40h  
000000014000821A  call        qword ptr [__imp_GetCurrentProcess (014012E060h)]  
0000000140008220  mov         qword ptr [rsp+30h],rax  
0000000140008225  call        qword ptr [__imp_GetCurrentProcessId (014012E068h)]  
000000014000822B  mov         rcx,qword ptr [rsp+30h]  
0000000140008230  mov         qword ptr [rsp+20h],rcx  
0000000140008235  mov         r9d,eax  
0000000140008238  xor         r8d,r8d  
000000014000823B  mov         edx,3Fh  
0000000140008240  mov         rcx,qword ptr [this]
  
0000000140008245  call        StackWalker::StackWalker (0140002F1Dh)  

000000014000824A  mov         rax,qword ptr [this]  
000000014000824F  lea         rcx,[StackWalkerToConsole::`vftable' (01400ED6C0h)]  
0000000140008256  mov         qword ptr [rax],rcx  
0000000140008259  mov         rax,qword ptr [this]  
000000014000825E  add         rsp,40h  
0000000140008262  pop         rdi
```

This compiler defined constructor is calling 2 WinApi functions: GetCurrentProcess and GetCurrentProcessId and calling the user-defined constructor for StackWalker.

Does anyone know why this is? I should mention, the parent class StackWalker does not have any user defined default constructors either.

If further information is required I'd be glad to supply it. Thank you for reading this far.

Edit: This is the github for the code: It's a tiny project, just 1 cpp file and 1 main.cpp file to test it. I'm assuming no one has the time and energy to go through the code, but putting it in here just in case.

In the post I'm referencing [Line 41](https://github.com/JochenKalmbach/StackWalker/blob/master/Main/StackWalker/main.cpp) from main.cpp and [Line 929](https://github.com/JochenKalmbach/StackWalker/blob/master/Main/StackWalker/StackWalker.cpp) from StackWalker.cpp

Comment: Is the whole class "special", like a builtin or something?  Backtracing up the call-stack normally requires special compiler support, not something that ISO C++ code can do portably, so it's easy to imagine there might be something special going on with how it's implemented.

Comment: Also, an implicitly-defined default constructor runs explicit default constructors for parent classes; that's normal.

Comment: @PeterCordes as far as I can tell it's not special. It backtraces up the call stack using the Win32 API, more specifically the Dbghelp.dll

Comment: Is this compiled with debug information? Insertion if stack checking code for example may be what you are looking at.

Comment: @Clifford could you rephrase that in a few more words haha? I did compile on debug.

Insertion of stack checking code? Does the compiler do that? I think there might be some confusion since the project I'm compiling is literally itself walking the callstack of another thread.

Comment: @PeterCordes Yeah, that is normal but the parent class has no default constructor as far as I could tell. That is, every constructor is taking in arguments that have no default values.

Comment: the body is empty, but before the constructor runs the members and base classes are initialized

Comment: To instantiate `StackWalkerToConsole`, **its default constructor must be called**, because you do not specify any => all bases and all elements must be default constructed. That includes the default constructing of `StackWalker`, and it seems that this one calls ` GetCurrentProcess()`.

Comment: @dalfaB Unless I'm misunderstanding, that implies that there exists a default constructor for StackWalker that calls GetCurrentProcess() and such. But in the code StackWalker doesn't have a default constructor. This is the [line](https://github.com/JochenKalmbach/StackWalker/blob/master/Main/StackWalker/StackWalker.cpp)  from the cpp file that was referenced.

Comment: @Horace - If any base classes or members of your class don't have a default constructor, then the compiler cannot automatically generate a default constructor.  Non-class members (e.g. of type `int`) will be default-initialised.

Comment: @Peter That's exactly why I'm confused. I'm assuming the constructor for StackWalkerToConsole was generated since there's no source code for it and Visual Studio only gives me the option to look at the dissasembly.

And looking through the code I couldn't find a default constructor for neither it or its parent class.

If that's a cold hard fact then I must be missing something somewhere in the code.

Comment: @Horace, look again. If `StackWalkerToConsole` inherits from `StackWalker` and you do not define any constructor, `StackWalker` is default constructible. You can try to create `StackWalker test;`, it is possible only if `StackWalker` has a default constructor.

Comment: @dalfaB You were right, I just missed it in the header file... Bit embarassing but I'll live

Comment: @Horace re: "_Does the compiler do that?_" quite possibly - depends what compiler you are using.  Certainly VC++ in Visual Studio debugger presents all sorts of information about the running process some of that at least probably requires the code to be _instrumented_.    Third party tools such as Valgrind on Linux will similarly instrument the code, it is not uncommon and need not be done by the compiler - profiler, bounds checker, code coverage, memory checking, stack checking tools etc. will all do that.

Comment: ... Simple experiment would be to compile without debug information (but same optimisation level), or any other dynamic analysis tool support, and see if the code is then omitted.

Comment: I'm going to vote to close because questions must be self-contained, not relying on external links to be answerable. Please construct a **short** [mre] that someone could copy from the question, compile, then run to reproduce your result.

Comment: @JaMiT I think that's fair since I don't think my question is going to help anyone.

It's just a case of: I'm a bit new at using the language and missed a default constructor within the header file of a class. I made the assumption that the class has no default constructor and all of the question is based on that premise. So if anything it's going to confuse more than help any readers.

There is no implicit created default constructor here after all. It's been defined in the source code.

Comment: @Horace *"It's just a case of: I'm a bit new at using the language and missed [something]"* -- One of the benefits of creating a minimal reproducible example is that it helps you find what you missed. ;) And the retention tends to be greater than learning from a Q&A.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The class you've referenced:

```cpp
class StackWalkerToConsole : public StackWalker
{
protected:
  virtual void OnOutput(LPCSTR szText) { printf("%s", szText); }
};
```

Has an implicitly-declared default constructor that looks similar to this:

```cpp
StackWalkerToConsole::StackWalkerToConsole() : StackWalker() {}
```

Which calls [this constructor](https://github.com/JochenKalmbach/StackWalker/blob/master/Main/StackWalker/StackWalker.h#L103-L106) of StackWalker:

```cpp
  StackWalker(int    options = OptionsAll,
              LPCSTR szSymPath = NULL,
              DWORD  dwProcessId = GetCurrentProcessId(),
              HANDLE hProcess = GetCurrentProcess());
```

(`StackWalker` *does* have a user-defined default constructor, it's this one that can be called with zero arguments)

So while there's no body of `StackWalkerToConsole`'s default constructor, its base class is initialized using the default arguments `StackWalker(OptionsAll, NULL, GetCurrentProcessId(), GetCurrentProcess())` and the body of the StackWalker constructor is run.

Comment: Thank you so much I feel like such an idiot. I'm a bit new to C++ and didn't imagine the default constructor would be defined in the header file since my brain was like: code go in cpp, declaration go in .h.

Comment: @Horace: The `StackWalker( int options = OptionsAll, ...` actually *is* just a declaration.  The definition is in some `.cpp` somewhere, called by the `call   StackWalker::StackWalker (0140002F1Dh)` in the implicitly-generated `StackWalkerToConsole::StackWalkerToConsole()` default constructor in the disassembly in your question.  The default values are themselves not simple, so that implicit default constructor which works as if it had an empty body `{}` in C++ terms still compiles to a significant amount of asm that makes 2 function calls to get the defaulted args for the parent constructor.

Comment: @PeterCordes Interesting, you're right it does still count as a declaration in spite of the default values for 2 of the arguments being calls to functions themselves. Thank you for your input

Answer (score 2):

Just focusing narrowly on your title question, namely...

> Could an implicit compiler created default constructor have more than a null body?

The C++20 Standard says:

An implicitly-defined (9.5.2) default constructor performs the set of initializations of the class that would be performed by a user-written default constructor for that class with no ctor-initializer (11.9.3) and an empty
compound-statement.

The IBM website you linked to claims *"The constructor will have no constructor initializer and a null body."* which I think is an attempt to paraphrase the same requirement.  As best I could find, the Standard only refers to "null body" once in [stmt.expr] - saying that an expression-statement without an expression can be useful in e.g. `while (condition) ;` to supply a null body to the iteration statement.  I'm not sure it's a good idea for IBM to use such a poorly, implicitly defined term, which some people might think means the default constructor isn't allowed to do anything.  What it does do is perform whatever initialisation the (virtual and non-virtual) bases need, including setting its own vtable pointer - if any - as the base class constructors run, and have all the non-static member constructors run based on any constructor arguments provided inline in the class definition, or failing that - using their default constructors.  So, an implicit default constructor can still be doing quite a lot of implicit work.

A "null body" doesn't mean calling the constructor is a no-op (i.e. *do-nothing* function).

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate the extra input there. I was indeed a bit misled by the term null body there. That's very good to know